# Android fragments strangely disappears when tag is set

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, tags

I've two types of `Fragment` in `PageView`. The first one is `TextFragment` containing `TextView` and having set **tag** on it. The other ones are `ImageFragment`s containing `ImageView` and having no **tag**. Images are loaded asynchronously from `asset` folder.

The problem is that the second (and sometimes also some other) fragment  does not show the content or the content appears just for a while and then disappears. When I remove/comment the line where the **tag** is set, everything starts to work perfectly.

Do you know how to have the fragment **appear correctly** even with the **tag set**?

Here is the code (using appcompat). Keep in mind that the **tag** is needed (in my app) although it's not queried here in the code.

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/activity_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context="example.com.testfragment.MainActivity">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/core_pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TEXTFR_TAG = "TEXTFR_TAG";
    static final String MYDATAFOLDER = "mydata";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.core_pager);
        final String[] imgs = getImages();
        viewPager.setAdapter(new FragmentStatePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()) {
            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return imgs.length + 1;
            }

            @Override
            public Fragment getItem(int position) {
                switch (position) {
                    case 0:
                        return TextFragment.newInstance(getSupportFragmentManager(), TEXTFR_TAG);
                    default:
                        return ImageFragment.newInstance(imgs[position - 1]);
                }
            }

        });

    }

    private String[] getImages() {
        try {
            return this.getAssets().list(MYDATAFOLDER);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return new String[0];
        }

    }

}
```

**fragment_text.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:background="@android:color/darker_gray">
    <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:id="@+id/textfragment_textview"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**TextFragment.java**

```
public class TextFragment extends Fragment {

    public TextFragment() {
    }

    static TextFragment newInstance(FragmentManager fragmentManager, String tag) {
        TextFragment instance = new TextFragment();
        fragmentManager
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.core_pager, instance, tag)      // <--- REMOVING THIS FIXES THE PROBLEM
                .commit();
        return instance;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_text, container, false);
        ((TextView)root.findViewById(R.id.textfragment_textview)).setText("SOME TEXT");
        return root;
    }
}
```

**fragment_image.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:background="@android:color/white">
    <ImageView android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:id="@+id/imagefragment_imageview"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**ImageFragment.java**

```
public class ImageFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String ARG_IMG = "ARG_IMG";

    public ImageFragment() {
    }

    static ImageFragment newInstance(String imagePath) {
        ImageFragment instance = new ImageFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_IMG, imagePath);
        instance.setArguments(args);
        return instance;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_image, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        if(view == null) {
            return;
        }

        final Bundle args = getArguments();
        final ImageView iv = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imagefragment_imageview);

        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Drawable>() {
            @Override
            protected Drawable doInBackground(Void... voids) {
                String imgFile = args.getString(ARG_IMG);
                try {
                    Context context = getContext().getApplicationContext();
                    return Drawable.createFromStream(context.getAssets().open(MainActivity.MYDATAFOLDER + '/' + imgFile), null);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("MyAPP", "Error: ", e);
                }
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Drawable drawable) {
                if(drawable != null) {
                    iv.setImageDrawable(drawable);
                } else {
                    Log.d("MyAPP", "No drawable");
                }
            }

        }.execute();
    }
}
```

Comment: i think that explicitly adding the Fragment instance to the FragmentManager in that replace() call is causing an unexpected behavior (as you have already noticed). i'd like to suggest that you don't really need that line. (maybe i'm wrong). i'm guessing you want to set that tag on the TextFragment instance so that you can retrieve it later.  could you perhaps retrieve that TextFragment instance from the FragmentStatePagerAdapter instance, by just getting the 0th item from it? i.e. create  FragmentStatePagerAdapter instance, save a ref to it, and then set that as the adapter on the ViewPager.